# Need help changing the max size of Facebook comment plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

The facebook comment works well until it is given too many comments and overlaps into the footer. Is there any way to limit the Facebook comment plugin to the point where it stays within a table and uses a sidebar to scroll up and down?
The url showing this is: http://cardspoiler.com/Bootstrap/Munter/Theme/Counterfeit_coin_bootstrap.html

Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <title>Cardspoiler - Counterfeit Coin</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../../../Cardspoiler_Title_Logo.tif">
    <meta name="description" content="BlackTie.co - Free Handsome Bootstrap Themes" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="themes, bootstrap, free, templates, bootstrap 3, freebie,">
    <meta property="og:title" content="">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-v=2.1.5.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,600,300,200&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<style>
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #232526;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #232526 , #414345);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #232526 , #414345);
    margin: 0em;
}
a { cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; }
footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 130px;
    background: #e4e6e5;
  background-color: rgba(228,230,229,.9);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    border-top: solid transparent 5px;
}
#content{
  padding: 70px 0 0 0;
}
#text-content{
    padding: 175px 0 0 0;
}
.col-aligncenter{float: none;margin: 0 auto;}
#locator { /* for the FB comments plugin */
  position: absolute; visibility: visible; left: 775px; top: -320px; height: 100px; width: 500px; z-index: 200;
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .container{
        max-width: 1200px;
    }
}
.fb_container{
   height: 400px;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" data-activeslide="1">
        <div class="container-fullwidth">

            <!-- .navbar-toggle is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="../../Navbar/Home.html">Cardspoiler</a>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse" >
                <ul class="nav row">
                    <li data-slide="1" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="home" title="Home"><span class="icon icon-home"></span> <span class="text">Home</span></a></li>
                    <li data-slide="2" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="warrior" title="Warrior" class="external nav"><span class="icon icon-filter"></span> <span class="text">Warrior</span></a></li>
                    <li data-slide="3" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="druid" title="Druid"><span class="icon icon-leaf"></span> <span class="text">Druid</span></a></li>
                    <li data-slide="4" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="priest"title="Priest"><span class="icon icon-plus-sign"></span> <span class="text">Priest</span></a></li>
                    <li data-slide="5" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="paladin" title="Paladin"><span class="icon icon-heart"></span> <span class="text">Paladin</span></a></li>
                    <li data-slide="6" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="hunter" title="Hunter"><span class="icon icon-screenshot"></span> <span class="text">Hunter</span></a></li>
          <li data-slide="7" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="mage" title="Mage"><span class="icon icon-fire"></span> <span class="text">Mage</span></a></li>
          <li data-slide="8" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="shaman" title="Shaman"><span class="icon icon-tint"></span> <span class="text">Shaman</span></a></li>
          <li data-slide="9" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="warlock" title="Warlock"><span class="icon icon-user"></span> <span class="text">Warlock</span></a></li>
          <li data-slide="10" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="rogue" htitle="Rogue"><span class="icon icon-eye-close"></span> <span class="text">Rogue</span></a></li>
          <li data-slide="11" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="minions" title="Minions"><span class="icon icon-chevron-up"></span> <span class="text">Minions</span></a></li>
          <li data-slide="12" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="spells" title="Spells"><span class="icon icon-chevron-down"></span> <span class="text">Spells</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-1 active-menu"></div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar -->
  <div class="table-responsive" id="content">
        <div class="container">
    <table class="table">
        <td valign="top">
          <img src="../../../../0/Counterfeit_Coin.png" align="left" class="img-responsive">
          <div id="center">
                    <div id="text-content">
          <font color="#888888" style="font-size:300%">
            Counterfeit Coin
          </font>
            <br>
s            <br>
            <font style="font-size:160%" color="9B764C">
            Cost:
          </font>
                    <font style="font-size:130%" color="#888888">
                    0
                    </font>
                    <br>
            <font style="font-size:160%" color="9B764C">
            Type:
            </font>
            <font style="font-size:130%" color="#888888">
            Spell
            </font>
            <br>
            <font style="font-size:160%" color="9B764C">
            Text:
            </font>
            <font style="font-size:130%" color="#888888">
            Gain 1 mana crystal this turn only.
                        <div id="right">
                            <div id="locator">
                            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                                <div class="fb_container">
                              <div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/cody.bontecou" align="right" data-width="500px" data-numposts="3"></div>
                            </div>
                                </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                        <br>
                        <br><br>
                        <br><br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
            </font>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
  <center>
        <footer>
            <div class="footer" id="footer">
                    <div class="container.customcontainer">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div align="right">
                                                <font color="888888" size="4%">CARDSPOILER.COM</font>
                                                <font color="9B764C" size="3%">
                                                <br>
                                                Freedom to know
                                                                                    </font>
                                                <br>
                                                                                        <br>
                                                <font size="2%" color="666666">
                                                We are here to bring you visual, leaked spoilers for all of <br> the cards you love within a simple gallery.
                                                <br>
                                                                                    </font>
                                                <font color="#333333">
                                                    <a href="mailto:help@cardspoiler.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:#9B764C;font-size:70%;">CONTACT US</a>
                                                    <a href="../../Privacy_Policy.html" style="text-decoration:none;color:#9B764C;font-size:70%;">PRIVACY POLICY</a>
                                                </font>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                                                        <div align="left">
                                            <font color="#888888" size="2%">
                                                <a href="MSoG.html" style="text-decoration: none;color:#888888;">Mean Streets of Gadgetzan</a>
                                            </font>
                                            <br>

                                            <font color="#888888" size="2%">
                                                <a href="ONiK.html" style="text-decoration: none;color:#888888;">One Night in Karazhan</a>
                                            </font>
                                            <br>

                                            <font color="#888888" size="2%">
                                                <a href="WotOG.html" style="text-decoration: none;color:#888888;">Whispers of the Old Gods</a>
                                            </font>
                                            <br>

                                            <font color="#888888" size="2%">
                                                <a href="tLoE.html" style="text-decoration: none;color:#888888;">The League of Explorers</a>
                                            </font>
                                            <br>

                                            <font color="#888888" size="2%">
                                                <a href="TGT.html" style="text-decoration: none;color:#888888;">The Grand Tournament</a>
                                            </font>
                                            <br>

                                            <font color="#888888" size="2%">
                                                <a href="BrM.html" style="text-decoration: none;color:#888888;">Blackrock Mountain</a>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                        </footer>


</body>

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack-v=2.1.5.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '220939261681295',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
  };
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
   $(function(){
   var navMain = $("#nav-main");
   navMain.on("click", "a", null, function () {
       navMain.collapse('hide');
   });
});
$(".fb_container").css("height","400px");
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not the sidebar, but the footer.

Add these rules to your code:

```
footer {
   z-index: 200;
}
#content {
   padding-bottom: 130px;
}
```

**Side note:** If you coded that layout, you should read some more about layouts, responsiveness and CSS do's and don'ts. If someone else made it for you, you probably want to have a chat with a professional web-developer.

Comment: So that worked, to a point. It's expanding the webpage with each comment but is still overlapping with the footer. I took a bit from a premade theme and am trying to learn web development on my own. This is a pretty sloppy mock-up of what I have made, I'm just putting this code into Github pages so I can work on the Facebook comment plugin. It doesn't show unless hosted online.

Comment: If you want to have vertical scroll for facebook plugin container, here's the code: `.fb_container {overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;}`. But I don't think it's not a decent solution. (you get two sidebars on small desktops).

Comment: Ah, that worked. Thank you. Any recommendation to have it work on all screen sizes?

Comment: From where I see it, there are a lot of things I'd change regarding your web page. It's difficult to make a short list and, actually, I already have: talk to a professional. However, the first thing I'd change is using a table for layout. Use either "flexbox" or "box model". This way you'll be able to make it responsive using media queries.